# Changing the format of a date field in an array in a react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a react app and I have an array called invoices below

```
    invoices[]
```

This is the content of the invoices array

```
    0:{invoiceId:123456,customerId: 2345, paymentDate:"2018-12-26T06:00:000+0000"}
    1:{invoiceId:623496,customerId: 2345, paymentDate:"2017-12-26T06:00:000+0000"}
    2:{invoiceId:523456,customerId: 2345, paymentDate:"2016-12-26T06:00:000+0000"}
```

I want to loop through the array and format the paymentDate with the code below
but this is not working. The format is not changing.

```
     this.state.invoices.forEach(function(cleanup){
          (moment(cleanup.paymentDate).format('MMM-DD-YYYY'));
        });
```

How can I achieve this? I don't want to change the structure of the array but 
just change the format of the paymentDate

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? If there is any.

Comment: it says cleanup is not defined

Comment: According to your question I guess its not cleanup but invoice.

Comment: So is the issue that its just giving you the wrong date? You should add more code to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Yes the date is wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do something like this (if you're not working with any date/time library - it's probably easier if you do):

```js
const invoices = [{
  invoiceId: 123456,
  customerId: 2345,
  paymentDate: "2018-12-26T06:00:000+0000"
}, {
  invoiceId: 623496,
  customerId: 2345,
  paymentDate: "2017-12-26T06:00:000+0000"
}, {
  invoiceId: 523456,
  customerId: 2345,
  paymentDate: "2016-12-26T06:00:000+0000"
}];

const getDate = el => new Date(el.paymentDate.substring(0, el.paymentDate.indexOf('T'))).toLocaleDateString("en-US");

console.log(invoices.map(el => ({ ...el,
  paymentDate: getDate(el)
})));
```

Comment: This works. I am actually using moment. Is it possible to get the paymentDate in this format Dec-26-2018?

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to update the states is as follows -

```
const invoice = this.state.invoice;
invoice.forEach(function(invoice) {
            const newDate = invoice.paymentDate.substring(0, invoice.paymentDate.indexOf('T'));
        invoice.paymentDate = moment(newDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('MMM-DD-YYYY');
        });

this.setState({
  invoice: invoice
})
```

Comment: @user2320476 this will work. Try and let me know if this works for you.